# I need a div to activate after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website www.polymath.io there is a menu div that basically is a little + sign in a box. Apparently this is hard to see for many so I'm wondering if I can somehow activate `div.mobile_menu.open`.

I need to go from default:

```
div.mobile_menu.close
```

to

```
div.mobile_menu.open
```

after 10 seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: The cathedral picture on your site is stunning. Which cathedral is it?

Comment: Heh, thank you. Honestly at the moment I don't remember. I know I thought the same about the beauty the first time I saw it so I wanted to make sure it was on the site. I know all those images came from ShutterStock. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `setTimeout()` function. See below:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Change menu to open here.
},10000);
```

The number at the end of the function is in milliseconds.

Comment: I'm a complete noob with javascript and jquery. Any chance you could give me a quick guide on what I'm doing? Thank you, jbw91!

Comment: I'd be happy to help how I can. Could you perhaps post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code so I can help you more?

Comment: Okay so after having inspected the code I have determined that the menu in question is a JQuery menu. All of the logic is in external JQuery files so I can't do anything with it without having access to far more of the websites' resources than I am probably allowed to have.

Comment: Can we connect on Skype somehow? Is there someway you can send me a message or I can send you one?